# TomEE server: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70 cannot be cast to xxx.class interface

Tags: java, ejb, apache-tomee

I want to access either remote or local EJB which is deployed in TomEE server.

My Client program is also deployed in the same. But when I look-up and cast it as interface it throws `ClassCastException`. 
Is there any particulate EJB path to look-up ?

My local/remote EJB jar log in TomEE server:

```
May 15, 2015 9:35:34 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureApplication
INFO: Configuring enterprise application: C:\Users\Sudhir\Desktop\apacheEjb\apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.1\webapps\remoteejb.jar
May 15, 2015 9:35:34 PM org.apache.openejb.config.InitEjbDeployments deploy
INFO: Auto-deploying ejb UuidSrvcImpl: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=UuidSrvcImpl)
May 15, 2015 9:35:34 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder build
INFO: Enterprise application "C:\Users\Sudhir\Desktop\apacheEjb\apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.1\webapps\remoteejb.jar" loaded.
May 15, 2015 9:35:34 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Assembling app: C:\Users\Sudhir\Desktop\apacheEjb\apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.1\webapps\remoteejb.jar
May 15, 2015 9:35:34 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=UuidSrvcImplLocal) --> Ejb(deployment-id=UuidSrvcImpl)
May 15, 2015 9:35:34 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/remoteejb/UuidSrvcImpl!com.service.uuidgen.UuidSrvc) --> Ejb(deployment-id=UuidSrvcImpl)
May 15, 2015 9:35:34 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/remoteejb/UuidSrvcImpl) --> Ejb(deployment-id=UuidSrvcImpl)
May 15, 2015 9:35:34 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initSingleton
INFO: Existing thread singleton service in SystemInstance(): org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@5a8fddea
May 15, 2015 9:35:34 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle startApplication
INFO: OpenWebBeans Container is starting...
May 15, 2015 9:35:34 PM org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader startUp
INFO: Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [CdiPlugin]
May 15, 2015 9:35:34 PM org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader startUp
INFO: Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [OpenWebBeansJsfPlugin]
May 15, 2015 9:35:34 PM org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer validateInjectionPoints
INFO: All injection points were validated successfully.
May 15, 2015 9:35:34 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle startApplication
INFO: OpenWebBeans Container has started, it took 16 ms.
May 15, 2015 9:35:34 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Created Ejb(deployment-id=UuidSrvcImpl, ejb-name=UuidSrvcImpl, container=Default Stateless Container)
May 15, 2015 9:35:34 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Started Ejb(deployment-id=UuidSrvcImpl, ejb-name=UuidSrvcImpl, container=Default Stateless Container)
May 15, 2015 9:35:34 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Deployed Application(path=C:\Users\Sudhir\Desktop\apacheEjb\apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.1\webapps\remoteejb.jar)
May 15, 2015 9:37:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Users\Sudhir\Desktop\apacheEjb\apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.1\webapps\ejb-examples-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT.war
May 15, 2015 9:37:24 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilde`enter code here`r init
```

My Client program is:

```
properties.setProperty("openejb.embedded.remotable", "false"); 
properties.setProperty("openejb.validation.output.level ", "medium");
properties.put("java.naming.factory.initial ",     "org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory");    
InitialContext initialContext  =     new InitialContext(properties);

        (UuidSrvc)initialContext.lookup("java:global/remoteejb/UuidSrvcImpl"); (Here I get error)
```

Comment: try the lookup without `java:global/`. in your case, it would be `(UuidSrvc)initialContext.lookup("remoteejb/UuidSrvcImpl");`

Comment: Thanks, but it is also not working. So I put @Local/@Remote annotation on the implementation  EJB class. Now it works. (On other servers like Jboss we need to put this annotation on Interface only)

Comment: what is the name of your ejb? what is name of remote interface?

Comment: also show the exception in the logs.